# Storyboard for iPhone-only application displaying iPad sizes?

Tags: xcode-storyboard

I am following along with a tutorial on Lynda.com and I am using XCode 6, while the tutorial uses XCode 5, so perhaps this is the problem. I have created a tabbed application and set devices to **iPhone** but my storyboard file looks like it's displaying iPad sizes. Why is this? My storyboards for other projects are not displayed like that.

Answer (score 0):

In Xcode 6 Main.storyboard is the single storyboard for all devices, no matter their screen size. Open the storyboard and you’ll see that it contains a single view controller, but of an unfamiliar size. Storyboards in previous versions of Xcode had to match the screen size of the target device. This clearly isn’t possible with the “one storyboard to rule them all” approach, so the storyboard is given an abstract size instead.

Please check this tutorial :
http://www.raywenderlich.com/83276/beginning-adaptive-layout-tutorial